# Can't find mobile device when using Web Bluetooth API

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth

I am learning Web Bluetooth API, using google dev console, I am unable to find my mobile device. Also tried Demos available on github
https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/demos

I am using chrome (dev),enabled webbluetooth flag chrome://flags, Ubuntu 16+, Android BLE 4.1 (Marshmallow)

```js
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        filters: [{
            services: ['battery_service']
        }]
    }).then(device => {
        console.log('Got device:', device.name);
        console.log('id:', device.id);
    });
```

Also tried after changing filter to `{name: 'Device Name'}`, still unable to find my mobile device. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

**PS:** Also tried BLE peripheral Simulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also give a try to https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/battery-level.html with the BLE peripheral Simulator? It should work on supported platforms. See https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#chrome

You mentioned Ubuntu 16+. As you can see in Linux requirements notes (https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#notes)

> Linux: Requires Kernel 3.19+ and BlueZ 5.41+ installed. Read [How to get Chrome Web Bluetooth working on Linux](https://acassis.wordpress.com/2016/06/28/how-to-get-chrome-web-bluetooth-working-on-linux/). Note that Bluetooth daemon needs to run with experimental interfaces: `sudo /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -E`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, i had already updated my kernel and installed BlueZ 5.42, and Bluetooth daemon is running on experimental interface, but still my mobile device is not showing in the list. 

Sir I have few questions:

1-)  Either every BLE supported device is compatible with this API, or should BLE devices also be supporting Advertising ( BLE Peripheral)? (In my case my android device can'not advertise, whenever i start BLE  Simulator it shows "LE Advertising is not available"  ). 

2-)  Can Web Bluetooth listen to Central LE as well ( my mobile is supporting Central LE)?

Comment: 1-) LE Advertising is not mandatory for using Web Bluetooth API as a GATT Client. 
2-) Not yet.