# Web Bluetooth on Chrome for Android is not finding any devices

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web, bluetooth

I'm trying to use the new `navigator.bluetooth` Web Bluetooth APIs to connect to an older Bluetooth device, however using the `requestDevice({acceptAllDevices: true})` method seems to not working.

According to the [docs](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/), it should show all of the bluetooth devices without any filters, but the Chrome beta on Android is not picking up any devices whatsoever, as seen in the picture.

I'm using the [Web Bluetooth Terminal](https://hewittwill.github.io/WebBluetooth-Terminal/) with the modified mentioned method above, and getting zero luck in listing any devices.

My device is not BLE, and I'm trying to use the SerialPort "SPP" profile similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5263144/1454514), which I believe has the UUID of `0x1101` or `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`.

How do I list the nearby or paired Bluetooth devices on Chrome mobile for Android?
(**Additional Info:** Chrome 56 on Android 6.0, the Bluetooth device is [a HC-05 module](https://www.google.com/search?q=HC-05&source=lnms&tbm=isch) - tested and confirmed working correctly with [a dozen of Android Bluetooth terminal apps](https://www.google.com/search?q=bluetooth+terminal+site:play.google.com).)

[image]

Comment: NOTE - [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40441258/1454514) does NOT help as my device is not a BLE device.

Comment: So you are using an API which specifically states its for Bluetooth 4.0 (or Bluetooth Low Energy) and you are wonder why it doesn't work for 'Classic' Bluetooth (3.0)?

Comment: @Morrison Chang I thought it could at least discover classic Bluetooth devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Bluetooth supports only Bluetooth Low Energy devices for now. You won't be able to connect to Bluetooth Classic devices with this Web API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Right, "For now".